# jQuery, jScrollPane and Long Content

Tags: jquery, .net, internet-explorer-9, browser, jscrollpane

I have an example of my issue hosted on my SkyDrive:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E95AD09917EEFAD1!292&authkey=!APYwAoPQ0tprs-A

I'm displaying content in a .NET WebBrowser control and using jScrollPane to make the content scrollable. The issues I'm getting occurs with large content being displayed. These issues don't seem to occur in Chrome or Firefox, but looking at the example in IE9 should show what I'm about to describe.

Issue #1 is that a large amount of content overflows to the right. The best example of this is when you first load the page, the top paragraph (actually a table cell) overflows on the right. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Issue #2 is that for some reason the calculation for the height of the scroll pane is not correctly working and content is being cut off at the bottom, as displayed here:

[image]

**Update:**

I ended up awarding my bounty to RedDevil79 because his answer was indeed a solution, however the white-space: pre-wrap is necessary to my project, so I couldn't simply remove it. My final solution was to add to the ".freetext tr td" elements a word-wrap: break-word style as well a dynamic padding-right that matched the width of the right scrollbar.

Comment: One other thing you'll notice is there is a white-space css style for freetext that needs to remains there.

Comment: please post some Code ! how do you fix something that doesnt exist .. if you have posted your code ppl would have helped you long time ago .. and setup a jsfiddle so ppl can help better

Comment: umm...The code is posted...on my skydrive...link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the right overflow is because you are using white-space: pre-wrap for the content, if you remove that it works ok. This should fix the height problem too, if not try to destroy and initialize again the object, like:

```
var ele = $('#Outer').jScrollPane(scrollSettings);
scrollAPI = ele.data('jsp');    
scrollAPI.destroy();
ele = $('#Outer').jScrollPane(scrollSettings);
scrollAPI = ele.data('jsp');
```

**EDIT:**

I discovered that using this when initialize the object you don't need to destroy and reconstruct every time the content is changed, and probably fix the height problem.

```
$("#Outer").jScrollPane({
    autoReinitialise:true,
    autoReinitialiseDelay: 1
});
```